# Regular expression: Match a string that contains no more than three consecutive Bs (without using negative lookahead)

Tags: regex

This is a simple question but I just recently started learning about regex.

I need to give a regex that describes all strings that contain no more than three consecutive `B`s.

It should match:

`sdBBdfsBBB`

`BfsBBBdsfBBB`

It shouldn't match:

`fsBBBBsfBB`

`BBBBBfsBBBsd`

I am not allowed to use negative lookahead, only fundamental operations and shortcuts and I have no idea how to solve this...
I know that the regex `.*B{1,3}.*` would match the strings that I want my regex to match but it would also match those I do not want my regex to match...

Answer (score 1):

how about providing proper negative matches before and after and repeat:

`^((^|[^B]*?)B{1,3}($|[^B]+?))+?$`

[test example](https://regex101.com/r/3rRh0H/3)

Update 2: matches `BBBxBBByBBB` correctly

REGEX explanation:

1. `(^|[^B]*?)` => match start of text or a possibly empty string of preceding non-B characters (non greedily)
2. `B{1,3}` => match consecutive B up to 3 times
3. `($|[^B]+?)` => match end of text or successive non-B characters (non-greedily)
4. Finaly `^(pattern)+?$` => match start of text, match inside pattern repeatedly (at least once), untill end of text

The updated regex matches ONLY the first 2 strings, the last 2 are not matched.

Comment: That doesn't work... `.*B{1,3}$` matches `BBBB` (the first `B` will just be munched by `.*`).

Comment: ok see updated regex, matches correctly only first 2 strings and have provided online test example

Comment: How can the updated version work with `BBBxBBByBBB`? `x` is used by left `B` group, and cannot be used on the central one...

Comment: @NikosM. Would this work:  (B{0,3}[^B]+)*B{0,3} | B{0,3}

Comment: @bananasananas No that doesnt match all required inputs, but why dont you [try it yourself](https://regex101.com/r/3rRh0H/4) and see

Comment: @bananasananas, yeap, that matches. The essense of the exercise is to understand to use negative matches here and there to restrict the regex to match only what is desired instead of using negative lookahead. So there are many variations of this approach as 3 different answers and your own approach shows. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

You can describe the expression as being a sequence of either a non-`B` or one to three `B`s followed by a non-`B` or by the end of the string.

```
^([^B]|B{1,3}([^B]|$))*$
```

- `^` begin of string
- `( ... )*` zero or more of...

  - `[^B]` something different from `B`
  - `|` or
  - `B{1,3}([^B]|$)` one to three `B`s followed by end of string or something different
- `$` end of string

If you want to exclude empty string just change the `*` into a `+` (that means "one or more").

Answer (score 1):

To not match empty strings, you could match either repeated sets of 1-3 times a B with at least any char except a B in between **or** match a string that ends with 1-3 times a B

```
^(?:[^B]*(?:B{1,3}[^B]+)+B{0,3}|[^B]*B{1,3})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^B]*` Match 0+ times any char except B
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `B{1,3}[^B]+` Repeat 1+ times 1-3 B's and 1+ times any char except B
  - `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
  - `B{0,3}` Match 0-3 B's at the end
  - `|` Or
  - `[^B]*B{1,3}` Match 0+ times any char except B and then 1-3 times a B
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uqAbAA/1)

If empty string are allowed, the pattern could be shortened to

```
^(?:[^B]*(?:B{1,3}[^B]+)*B{0,3})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S41tfJ/1)

**Note** that negated character class `[^B]` matches any char except a B and could possibly also match a newline. To not allow newlines to match, use `[^B\r\n]` or `[^B\s]` to exclude whitespace chars.

Comment: Why should be empty strings excluded?

Comment: I am not stating that it should, my answer is if the OP does not want to match empty strings. The example pattern `.*B{1,3}.*` matches 1-3 times a B so perhaps empty strings are not desired.